# HMAC-MD5 signature - translate key from hex to byte format php

Tags: php, hex, byte

I need to digitally sign some post data using HMAC-MD5 algo.

I have the key and a sample string (to which I know what the hex sign should be.

My problem is when I use the hash_hmac php function the key it generates is different to what it should be.

The instructions are:

1. translate HMAC key from hex to byte format - *not sure how to do that*
2. sign the string using HMAC-MD5 procedure based on merchant’s HMAC
   key - *this bit is fine*
3. translate signature from byte to hex format and associate it as
   value with parameter sign - *not sure what to do here either*

I've tried using this for step 1) $key2 = pack("H*" , $key)
and this for step 2) bin2hex ( $sign ) which don't work as hoped.

The only online HMAC-MD5 generator that I've found that produced the correct sign is here: 
http://membres.multimania.fr/brudav/hash.php when 'hexa' is selected. I obviously don't know how this works it out though.

Can anyone offer me any advise?

Comment: `hash_hmac` does not generate a key. It hashes the input data, and by default returns the output as hex string. Use the `raw_output` parameter to get binary output. -- Show your code and how the result differs from the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

```
$hmac = hash_hmac('md5', $data, hex2bin($key));
```

should give the same answer as the online calculator.

- [`hex2bin`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) converts the key from hex format to binary format (step 1), which `hash_hmac` expects. What you had tried with `pack` should also work for this purpose.
- [`hash_hmac`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php), with the default `$raw_output = false`, will produce a hex output (steps 2 and 3 combined).